# JSON to object using C# JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to create a list of Movies from a JSON-string fetched from an API (testing with a string-variable so far). My Movie-class:

```
private string title { get; set; }
private int year { get; set; }
private string releaseDate { get; set; }

public override String ToString()
{
    return title + " (" + year + "): " + releaseDate;
}
```

The code below however does not insert anything into the Movie-objects. A little time ago it created 2 objects (which is right because it's 2 movies in the JSON-string), but with no content what-so-ever. Now I'm stuck with nothing, the code does not create any objects.

```
string json = "{\"movies\": [{\"title\": \"Something\",\"year\": \"1999\",\"releaseDate\": \"1234\"},{\"title\": \"Something2\",\"year\": \"1992\",\"releaseDate\": \"1235\"}]}";

List<Movie> movieList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Movie>>(json);
```

It's obvious that I'm quite new to this, but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem elsewhere 'cause either it's not the same issue as I have or I can't find the difference between my code and the solution.

What am I missing here? Does the variable-names have to be the same in the Movie-class as in the JSON-string?

**EDIT:** I finally found my second problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24964815/3355350). Turns out it's wrong to write private when you use auto properties. Also see [{ get; set; } syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096926/what-is-the-get-set-syntax-in-c).

Comment: Did you try like this?          string json = "[{\"title\": \"Something\",\"year\": \"1999\",\"releaseDate\": \"1234\"},{\"title\": \"Something2\",\"year\": \"1992\",\"releaseDate\": \"1235\"}]";

Comment: Not exactly like that, but I did try with only one movie with {}.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use JSON.NET by Newtonsoft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is an object that contains a "movies" property that is an array:

```
{
    movies: [
        {
            "title": "Something"
        },
        {
            "title": "Something Else"
        }
    ]
}
```

To deserialize it, you need an object with a "movies" property like this:

```
class MoviesObject {
    public List<Movie> movies { get; set; }
}

List<Movie> movieList = new JavaScriptSerializer().
    Deserialize<MoviesObject>(json).movies;
```

Comment: So I need an object that contains the outer list like in the JSON as well? Thanks so far, I have now 2 empty objects again. My output:
`(0):
 (0):`

Comment: You shouldn't be using fields for your JSON DTOs. You should NEVER have public fields. Use properties instead.